# How to convert string in list of lists to float in place?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
my_list=[['A','B','C','0.0'],['D','E','F','1.0'],['G','H','I','0'],['J','K','L','M']
```

I've tried doing

```
new_list=[[float(x) for x in i if x.isnumeric()] for i in my_list]
```

**Output**

```
[[0.0],[1.0],[0],[]]
```

**Expected output**

```
[['A','B','C',0.0],['D','E','F',1.0],['G','H','I',0],['J','K','L','M']
```

I don't know how to turn the final values into a float and modify the values in place, I've tried appending. I've tried the answers to other questions too but they created a new list, but I want to change the original list.

**EDIT** Changed my list to include decimals. The below answers worked if the numbers (string) were '0' but not decimals '0.0' or '1.0'.

Comment: Just to make it clear, that's not in-place. Are you looking for another way, or thinking this is in-place?

Answer (score 5):

You need to keep `x` if `x` is not numeric. You are close:

```
>>> my_list = [['A','B','C','0'], ['D','E','F','1'], ['G','H','I','J']]
>>> new_list = [[float(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in i] for i in my_list]
>>> new_list
[['A', 'B', 'C', 0.0], ['D', 'E', 'F', 1.0], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J']]
```

Note the `if x.isnumeric() else x` inside the list comprehension, and that it's at the beginning of the comprehension, not the end (since it's a ternary conditional)

---

As you've noticed, this is creating a new list, not modifying the original. If you want to keep the original list, a basic for-loop would be better:

```
for i, sublist in enumerate(my_list):
    for j, x in enumerate(sublist):
        try:
            my_list[i][j] = float(x)
        except ValueError:
            pass

[['A', 'B', 'C', 0.0], ['D', 'E', 'F', 1.0], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J']]
```

Comment: Rightly or wrongly, the question title says "in place", and this is not an in-place modification.

Comment: @alaniwi I was just typing it up as you commented that :P

Comment: Okay fair enough. (Not my downvote, BTW.) Though I think I would just loop with `for sublist in my_list:` and in the assignment use `sublist[j] = float(x)` - can't quite see the need for the `i`.

Comment: @alaniwi True, yep. Too much C in my head recently -- I'll keep my syntax since it's similar to the list comprehension

Comment: @TerryA This almost worked, I should've phrased my question better (now edited).

Comment: @catzen You're better off trying to cast `x` to a float and catching the error. I've edited my answer

Comment: `'1.0'.isnumeric()` returns `False` so the list-comprehension version is wrong according to the input in the question

Answer (score 3):

Assign to `my_list[:]` to modify it inplace. Use a [ternary `if`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) instead of the [comprehensions `if` filter](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) to keep all items.

```py
#       v modify list instead of replacing it
my_list[:] = [[float(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in i] for i in my_list]
#                       ^ ternary if provides a value for each element
```

---

If the *nested* lists must be modified in-place, consider using a loop to explicitly access each sub-list. If memory consumption is a goal, use a generator expression (`(...)`) instead of a list comprehension (`[...]`) for the new elements.

```py
for sub_list in my_list:
    sub_list[:] = (float(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in sub_list)
```

To convert *all* float values, not just those that are purely digits, use `try`-`except`. `str.isnumeric` will for example reject `'12.3'`.

```py
def try_float(literal: str):
    try:
        return float(literal)
    except ValueError:
        return literal

for sub_list in my_list:
    sub_list[:] = (try_float(x) for x in sub_list)
```

Comment: This still creates a whole new list and copies it instead of modifying the original

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes but isn't that the problem? What if we don't want to use up any extra memory

Comment: @TerryA It *modifies* the original list to include all elements of the new list. See the updated variant for a deep modification.

Comment: @TerryA well the old one will be released immediately probably and all references to the list will see the changes so I believe it achieves the same goal

Comment: @TerryA Using a generator now to avoid extra list in memory.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This almost worked, I should've phrased my question better (now edited).