# Changing all strings except one in a list of lists to a float

Tags: python

I have a list of lists:

```
LofL = [["string", "number", "number", "number"], ["string", "number", "number", "number"], ...]
```

and im trying to turn the numbers within the list of lists to floats instead of strings. Each list of list is not equal in length. So far I have:

```
for sublist in LofL:
sublist[1:] = float(sublist[1:])
```

but I'm getting the error *float argument must be a string or real number not a list*. This works for single numbers if I do `sublist[1] = float(sublist[1])` but I'm unsure of how to include all numbers in each list of lists without the [1:] indexing.

Comment: Related: [How to convert string in list of lists to float in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63481642/6045800)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for sublist in LofL:
    for i in range(1, len(sublist)):
        sublist[i]=float(sublist[i])
```

Explanation:
Your initial code `sublist[1:]=float(sublist[1:]` will not work as `sublist[1:]` is a list and you cannot turn list to a float.

So the `for i in range(1, len(sublist)` will iterate through each element in your `sublist`
then with each iteration we will convert `sublist[i]=float(sublist[i]` into float. Because you specified that the first item of sublist does not need to change hence we are starting our loop from 1

Comment: Would someone mind explaining where I went wrong so I may understand why this is correct?

Comment: added explanation in the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to the other answer here. I'm just including it because it seems like the reassignment of a slice of the list is what you were going for in your original code:

```
LofL = [["string", '1', '2', '3'], ["string", '4', '5', '6', '7']]

for sublist in LofL:
    sublist[1:] = map(float, sublist[1:])

print(LofL)
# [['string', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], ['string', 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The excellent answer from @Mark solves your particular problem. However, there is an implicit assumption that the first element of each sub-list should be ignored and that subsequent elements can be converted to float.

Here's a simple double loop that will try to convert **all** elements. This would allow for the 'string' component to be anywhere in the list.

```
LofL = [["string", "42", "42", "1"], ["string", "2.5", "100", "20"], [5, 'string']]

for e in LofL:
    for i, v in enumerate(e):
        try:
            e[i] = float(v)
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(LofL)
```

**Output:**

```
[['string', 42.0, 42.0, 1.0], ['string', 2.5, 100.0, 20.0], [5.0, 'string']]
```